# distribution and measures on $\mathbb{R}_+$

Tags: probability-theory

> (Probability and Stochastic by Cinlar, Exercise 5.14, Page 33) Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}_+$ (with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra) such that $c(t) = \mu[0,t]$ is finite for every $t$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$. The limit $b = c(\infty) = \lim_{t \to \infty} c(t)$ is allowed to be $+\infty$.

> a) Show that $c$ is increasing and right-continuous. It is called the cumulative distribution function associated with $\mu$.

> b) Define $a(u)$ as in 5.13 for $u \in [0,b)$, let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $[0,b)$. Show that
> $$\mu = \lambda \circ a^{-1}.$$

In 5.13, $a(u) = \inf \{ t \in \mathbb{R}_+: c(t) > u\}$. I showed that $a(u)$ is right continuous and increasing, and also $c(t) = \inf \{u \in [0, b): a(u) > t\}$. I can do a), but I am struggling with b). For fixed $t$,
$$\mu[0,t] = c(t) = \inf \{u \in [0, b): a(u) > t\} = \inf a^{-1}(t, \infty).$$
This is what I can think of so far. Can you give some help?

Edit: I was thinking about this problem. Maybe, it has something to do with
$$\lambda \circ a^{-1}[0,t] = \lambda[0, c(t)] = c(t) = \mu[0,t].$$
If this is the correct way to solve it, the problem comes down to showing the first equality. I think $a(0) = 0$ because $c(0) = 0$ and $c(\cdot)$ is right continuous (which implies that it is not possible to a jump at $0$ as $0$ is the smallest value of $c(\cdot)$). However, for some positive $u$, it is possible that $a(u) = t$, but $c(t) > u$ when $c(t)$ has a jump at $t$. In this case, the first equality does not seem true...

Edit2: Notice that
$$a^{-1}[0,t] = \{u \in [0,b): a(u) \le t\}$$
Let $u^* = \sup\{u \in [0,b): a(u) \le t\}$. Then, if there is a jump at $u^*$, it could be that $a(u^*)>t$, but it is still true that  $a(u) < t$ for all $u < u^*$. Thus, $a^{-1}[0,t] = [0, u^*]$. In addition, we have a result from [here](https://www.scirp.org/pdf/AM_2012123110083732.pdf) that $u^* = \inf\{u \in [0,b): a(u) > t\} = c(t)$. Thus, $\lambda[0,c(t)] = c(t)$, which completes the proof. Please let me know if it is wrong.